# Laravel Protecting Columns from Mass Assignment that Aren't Nullable/Default Values

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel, security

I am trying to make the 'name' and 'email' properties **guarded** in my user model, because I don't want my users to be able to change them after registration.

My user model looks like this:

```
protected $fillable = [
    'province',
    'city',
    'street',
    'postal',
    'cellphone',
    'facebook',
    'instagram',

];

protected $guarded = [
  'name',
  'email',
  'password',
  'account_type',
  'verified_type',
];
```

Upon registration, Laravel by default mass assigns these values like so:

```
//Create the user
      $user = User::create([
          'name' => $data['name'],
          'email' => $data['email'],
          'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
          'province' => $data['province'],
          'city'  => $data['city'],
          'street'  => $data['street'],
          'postal'  => $data['postal'],
          'cellphone' => $data['cellphone'],
          'trial_ends_at' => \Carbon\Carbon::now()->addMonths(3),
          'account_type' => $accountType,
      ]);
```

But this throws an error for me because 'name' doesn't have a default value and isn't nullable. I understand why I'm getting the error and how to fix it, but I would like to know how I should go about assigning the name and email if they don't have default/nullable properties. For example, something like:

```
$user = new User();
$user->name = $request->name;
$user->email = $request->email;
$user->save();

$user->update([
  //the rest of the mass assignable values
]);
```

Or is there an easier way?

Comment: From [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent) (find Mass Assignment section). "Of course, you should use either  `$fillable` or `$guarded` - not both."

Comment: Ah, thank you. I can easily remove one -- but this demonstrates explicitly what I'm trying to get across :)

Comment: You need to accept 'name' & 'email' only while registering, not while updating ?

Comment: Correct, I don't want them to be able to change their identity

Comment: For what you are trying to achieve, you can try using observers to where you would pass `$request->all()` and then filter keys. [Credits](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/eloquent/eloquent-different-guarded-for-update).

Comment: @Vranvs Why don't you just drop them from request while updating?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can accomplish by adding this to your model.

```
/*
    Attribute which are protected from updating.
*/

protected $protected = [
    'name', 'email'
];

protected static function boot()
{
    parent::boot();

    static::saving(function ($model) {
        if($model->id){
            foreach($model->protected as $attribute){
                $model->$attribute = $model->getOriginal($attribute);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Hope the code is self-expresive.

Answer (score 0):

you can use a mutator and remove name from guarded attributes. [read the docs here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-mutators)

```
public function setNameAttribute($newName)
{
  if(isset($this->name) && $this->name !== null){
    throw new \Exception;
    //or do nothing
  } else {
    $this->attributes['name'] = $newName;
  }
}
```

and do the same  for email too